# How to set custom controls icon for Android Studios Component Designer?

Tags: android, android-xml

How can I set the small icon that appears in Android Studio's ComponentTree?
As you can see on this picture, it is possible to set one, as RadioButtons, Buttons and all the other views present custom images to the developer, while my control shows the standard green Droid.

[image]

If you look close at the `LinearLayouts` involved in the picture, it must be something dynamic, as even the `orientation` (hor, vert) is displayed correctly.
Any hints, how this can be done? Thanks in advance.